# Sinatra pass variables to erb

Tags: ruby, sinatra

There's two ways I can do this.

First is to use `:locals => {....}` and other is to use `@var_name`. I am just wondering which one is better/preferred? I couldn't find the answer to this anywhere.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have no experience but probably you write less code using `@var_name`, but if let's say you have 2 actions which render the same view with different objects let's say one with foo and the other with bar, you probably would want to use locals.

```
def foos
  foos = Foo.all
  erb :something, locals: {list: foos} 
end

def foos
  bars = Foo.all
  erb :something, locals: {list: bars} 
end
```

Instead of @vars, wich you have to use the same var_name that does not truly represent what's inside. Like: It's a list of what??

```
def bars
  @list = Bar.all
  erb :something
end

def foos
  @list = Foo.all
  erb :something 
end
```

Or maybe you should be good with @vars, because most of the time you reuse a view when you render the same kind of objects like:

```
def foos
  @foos = Foo.all
  erb :something
end

def bar_foos
  @foos = Foo.where(bar: true)
  erb :something 
end
```

So you probably just want to use locals when rendering partials wich most of the time are used in different contexts. Like a form when you render for a @new_bar, and and existing @bar. Just an example. Or for example a @current_user or a simple @user

Comment: Good answer. My 2 cents - wherever possible, restrict the scope of a variable. I always use locals if I can (the Rails reliance on instance variables makes me shudder!) The absurd counterpoint would be, why not use global variables? They're seen as bad because of the lack of scope, and instance variables are no different. Where I do use instance variables is in passing values to the layout (titles, extra stylesheet references…), and values set in `before` and `after` handlers.